# How to validate and reference digraph /special character in Vim?

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expression

I want to remove the ending section of my output that typically follows the below pattern:

`^[[2D[^[D` but my regex will not allow me to select the `^[` parts of the word. Note on my Vim that part shows in a different color almost like it is a a digraph or special character.

Any thoughts on how I can create a mapping to remove this from my outputs?

Note when I copied the output to my clipboard and pasted into my browser it translated the `^[` to ``

```
I am writing to you today as an email full of typos. Ye^[[2D[^[K
Yes, you heard that right – I'm a bit of a typo-ridden mess. But don't worry, I've got fa^[[2D^[[K
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special character `^[` is actually <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you want to include it in a regex you can type it using the following key sequence:

<kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>

In general in presence of a special character you can discover its code using the `ga` command. Move the cursor on the character and hit `ga`.

The output gives you:

- The decimal code (`27` in case of Esc)
- The hexadecimal code (`1b` in case of Esc)
- The digraph if any (`EC` in case of Esc)

You can use that information to reinsert the same character in insert mode:

- <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>`027`
- <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd>`x1b`
- <kbd>Ctrl k</kbd>`EC`

Comment: Teach 'em to fish: you might mention `ga`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can just copy the offending text (`y`ank into a register) and paste it into your replacement expression without knowing (or caring) what the special characters are.

`:%s/`<kbd>CTRL-R</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>`//g`

See `:help c_CTRL-R` for details.